# How to run access form with sequential ordered parameters from Excel and return values

Tags: excel, vba, forms, ms-access, parameters

A rookie here.  I have an Excel VBA code with the intent to pass 4 values from Excel into an Access form and return 2 results.  The form, developed by another team, is a good form our engineers use.  My goal is to use the form’s process, when we have several rows of data in Excel, that populate their respective returned values.

The form’s sequential process is:

1. User enters a “Conn PN” into an unbound text box cmbEntry, it runs queries, qryCmbPinNumber and  qryCmbCAVNOLst.
2. User enters “Cav No” into an unbound text box cmbPinNmbr, it runs queries, qryCmbLst, qryWrSzOptns, and  qryCmbEntryLst.
3. User enters “Terminal Type” into unbound cmb box cmbx_trmlProperty, it runs queries qryCBLSEALPNCONV, qryWrCblSeal, and qryWrSZRng1.
4. User enters “Wire Size” into an unbound text box qryWrSZRng1, it runs qryTERMPNCONV and qryWrSzRng.
   The results are put into text boxs txtbx_trmnlPN,  txtbx_MinWr , txtbx_MaxWr and txtbx_cblseal.

Below is the VBA code, in which I’m getting an **Object-variable or With block variable not set**.  Aside from the error, I’m not confident I have good code, especially with the required sequence.

Appreciate any support,  :)

```
Sub PassParametersToAccess()

    Dim AccessApp As Object
    Dim db As Object
    Dim form As Object
    Dim TermPN As Variant
    Dim cmbEntry As Variant
    Dim cmbx_trmlProperty As Variant
    Dim Wiresize As Variant
    Dim txtbox_WrSz As Variant
    Dim cmbPinNmbr As Variant
    Dim txtbx_trmnlPN As String
    Dim txtbx_cblseal As String
    Dim result1 As String
    Dim result2 As String

    Set AccessApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")

    AccessApp.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\Users\Engineering\Terminal_Values_R5 WITH CABLE SEAL_REMOTE_PLAY.accdb"

    Set db = AccessApp.CurrentDb
    Set form = db.OpenForm("frmTrmVl")

    AccessApp.Forms("frmTrmVl").Controls("cmbEntry").Value = "7283-8854-30"
    form.Requery
    AccessApp.Forms("frmTrmVl").Controls("cmbPinNmbr").Value = "7"
    form.Requery
    AccessApp.Forms("frmTrmVl").Controls("cmbx_trmlProperty").Value = "Tin"
    AccessApp.Forms("frmTrmVl").Controls("txtbox_WrSz").Value = "0.5"
    form.Requery

    AccessApp.DoCmd.Close "frmTrmVl"

    result1 = form.Controls("txtbx_trmnlPN").Value
    result2 = form.Controls("txtbx_cblseal").Value

    AccessApp.Quit
    Set AccessApp = Nothing

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E1").Value = result1
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F1").Value = result2
    
End Sub
```

[image: Formview with inputs]
[image: Form in Design View]

@Shahram
First, thank your for your help.
I used the code, which I have no access to form code.  I updated the code to the following:
`        Option Explicit

```
    Sub Term_PN()
    
    Dim Result1 As String
    Dim Result2 As String
    Dim AccessApp As New Access.Application
    Dim FRM As Access.Form
    
    
    AccessApp.OpenCurrentDatabase ("C:\Users\t0989sp\Documents\Engineering\FCA_Terminal_Values_R5 WITH CABLE SEAL_REMOTE_PLAY.accdb")
    
    AccessApp.Visible = True ' REQUIRED TO ENABLE FOCUS IN FORM CONTROLS
    
    AccessApp.DoCmd.OpenForm "frmTrmVl"
    Set FRM = AccessApp.Forms!frmTrmVl
    
    FRM.Controls("cmbEntry").SetFocus
    FRM.Controls("cmbEntry").Value = "7283-8854-30"
     
    FRM.Controls("cmbPinNmbr").SetFocus
    FRM.Controls("cmbPinNmbr").Value = "7"
    
    FRM.Controls("cmbx_TrmlPrprty").SetFocus
    FRM.Controls("ccmbx_TrmlPrprty").Value = "Tin"
    
    FRM.Controls("txtbox_WrSz").SetFocus
    FRM.Controls("txtbox_WrSz").Value = "0.5"
    
    FRM.BTN_Wire_Ranges.SetFocus
    FRM.BTN_Wire_Ranges_Click ' IF REQUIRED
    SendKeys "{ENTER}", True  ' IF REQUIRED
    
    Result1 = FRM.Controls("txtbx_trmnlPN").Value
    Result2 = FRM.Controls("txtbx_cblseal").Value
    
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E1").Value = Result1
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F1").Value = Result2
    
    AccessApp.CloseCurrentDatabase
    AccessApp.Quit
    
    End Sub
```

`
I get the error #2110 Access can't move the focus to the control cmbPinNmbr. If I ignore the error, then the next set focus gets the same error.

I do have access to the form code and I think made the variables Public.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Public cmbPinNmbr As String
Public cmbx_TrmlPrprty As String
Public txtbx_WrSz As Byte
Public cmbEntry As String

Private Sub cmbEntry_AfterUpdate()
Me.cmbPinNmbr.Requery
Me.cmbPinNmbr.Visible = True
Me.lbl_PinNmbr.Visible = True
Me.cmbPinNmbr.Value = ""
Me.cmbx_TrmlPrprty.Value = ""
Me.txtbx_WrSz.Value = ""
Me.lbl_Rslts.Visible = False
Me.lbl_trmnlPN.Visible = False
Me.txtbx_trmnlPN.Visible = False
Me.lbl_MinWr.Visible = False
Me.lbl_MaxWr.Visible = False
Me.txtbx_MinWr.Visible = False
Me.txtbx_MaxWr.Visible = False
Me.cmd_WrRngbttn.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub cmbPinNmbr_AfterUpdate()
Me.cmbx_TrmlPrprty.Visible = True
Me.lbl_TrmlPrprty.Visible = True
Me.cmbx_TrmlPrprty.Value = ""
Me.txtbx_WrSz.Value = ""
Me.lbl_Rslts.Visible = False
Me.lbl_trmnlPN.Visible = False
Me.txtbx_trmnlPN.Visible = False
Me.lbl_MinWr.Visible = False
Me.lbl_MaxWr.Visible = False
Me.txtbx_MinWr.Visible = False
Me.txtbx_MaxWr.Visible = False
Me.cmd_WrRngbttn.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub cmbx_TrmlPrprty_AfterUpdate()
Me.txtbx_WrSz.Visible = True
Me.lbl_WrSz.Visible = True
Me.txtbx_WrSz.Value = ""
Me.lbl_Rslts.Visible = False
Me.lbl_trmnlPN.Visible = False
Me.txtbx_trmnlPN.Visible = False
Me.lbl_MinWr.Visible = False
Me.lbl_MaxWr.Visible = False
Me.txtbx_MinWr.Visible = False
Me.txtbx_MaxWr.Visible = False
Me.cmd_WrRngbttn.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub cmdClr_Click()
Me.txtbx_cblseal.Visible = False
Me.cmbPinNmbr.Visible = False
Me.lbl_PinNmbr.Visible = False
Me.cmbPinNmbr.Visible = False
Me.lbl_TrmlPrprty.Visible = False
Me.cmbx_TrmlPrprty.Visible = False
Me.lbl_WrSz.Visible = False
Me.txtbx_WrSz.Visible = False
Me.cmbEntry.Value = ""
Me.txtbx_WrSz.Value = ""
Me.cmbx_TrmlPrprty.Value = ""
Me.txtbx_WrSz.Value = ""
Me.lbl_Rslts.Visible = False
Me.lbl_trmnlPN.Visible = False
Me.txtbx_trmnlPN.Visible = False
Me.lbl_MinWr.Visible = False
Me.lbl_MaxWr.Visible = False
Me.txtbx_MinWr.Visible = False
Me.txtbx_MaxWr.Visible = False
Me.cmd_WrRngbttn.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub txtbx_WrSz_AfterUpdate()
Me.txtbx_trmnlPN.Requery
Me.txtbx_MinWr.Requery
Me.txtbx_MaxWr.Requery
Me.lbl_Rslts.Visible = True
Me.lbl_trmnlPN.Visible = True
Me.lbl_MinWr.Visible = True
Me.lbl_MaxWr.Visible = True
Me.txtbx_trmnlPN.Visible = True
Me.txtbx_MinWr.Visible = True
Me.txtbx_MaxWr.Visible = True
Me.txtbx_cblseal.Visible = True
End Sub
```

For the excel vba code, Its the same code you had provided with the added lines:

Result1 = FRM.Controls("txtbx_trmnlPN").Value
Result2 = FRM.Controls("txtbx_cblseal").Value

I get the error 40036 Method of 'Item' of object 'Forms' failed.

I'm guessing the code with access to the form code is better than the other code.

Again, thx for your help.

Comment: What line triggers error? Since you have a declared and set form object, why not use it instead of the longer AccessApp reference for populating controls? `form.cmbEntry = "7283-8854-30"` Why would you need to Requery form?

Comment: I would expect `AccessApp.DoCmd.Close "frmTrmVl"` to error. Close the declared and set form object, but after lines that reference form controls populating result1 and result2 variables.

Answer (score 0):

First, instead of late-bounding (createobject) , add a reference to MS Access Object Library to enable early-binding and access to methods and properties during coding.

**If you have access to the form module:**

In access form, Change combos and the button events to PUBLIC and edit your code:

```
DIM AccessApp AS NEW Access.Application
AccessApp.OpenCurrentDatabase ("C:\Users\Engineering\Terminal_Values_R5 WITH CABLE SEAL_REMOTE_PLAY.accdb")

AccessApp.DoCmd.OpenForm "frmTrmVl"

DIM FRM As Access.FORM
SET FRM= AccessApp.Forms!frmTrmVl

FRM.Controls("cmbEntry").Value = "7283-8854-30"
FRM.cmbEntry_afterupdate

FRM.Controls("cmbPinNmbr").Value = "7"
FRM.cmbPinNmbr_afterupdate

FRM.Controls("cmbx_trmlProperty").Value = "Tin"
FRM.cmbx_trmlProperty_afterupdate

FRM.Controls("txtbox_WrSz").Value = "0.5"
FRM.txtbox_WrSz_afterupdate ' IF REQUIRED
FRM.BTN_Wire_Ranges_Click ' IF REQUIRED

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E1").Value = result1
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F1").Value = result2

AccessApp.CloseCurrentDatabase
AccessApp.Quit
SET AccessAccessApp= NOTHING
```

**If you have not access to form codes:**

```
DIM AccessApp AS NEW Access.Application
AccessApp.OpenCurrentDatabase ("C:\Users\Engineering\Terminal_Values_R5 WITH CABLE SEAL_REMOTE_PLAY.accdb")

AccessApp.visible=TRUE ' REQUIRED TO ENABLE FOCUS IN FORM CONTROLS

AccessApp.DoCmd.OpenForm "frmTrmVl"

DIM FRM As Access.FORM
SET FRM= AccessApp.Forms!frmTrmVl

FRM.Controls("cmbEntry").setfocus
FRM.Controls("cmbEntry").Value = "7283-8854-30"

FRM.Controls("cmbPinNmbr").setfocus
FRM.Controls("cmbPinNmbr").Value = "7"

FRM.Controls("cmbx_trmlProperty").setfocus
FRM.Controls("cmbx_trmlProperty").Value = "Tin"

FRM.Controls("txtbox_WrSz").setfocus
FRM.Controls("txtbox_WrSz").Value = "0.5"

FRM.BTN_Wire_Ranges.setfocus 
FRM.BTN_Wire_Ranges_Click ' IF REQUIRED
SENDKEYS "{ENTER}" , TRUE ' IF REQUIRED

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E1").Value = result1
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F1").Value = result2

AccessApp.CloseCurrentDatabase
AccessApp.Quit
SET AccessAccessApp= NOTHING
```